# PanacheRepositoryResource - Transaction is not active

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm using Quarkus with Hibernate Rest Data Panache and I'm having issues while persisting data with a custom endpoint.

```java
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.rest.data.panache.PanacheRepositoryResource;
import io.quarkus.rest.data.panache.ResourceProperties;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;

@ResourceProperties
public interface EntityResource extends PanacheRepositoryResource<EntityRepository, Entity, Long> {

        @POST
        @Path("/foo")
        @Transactional
        default Entity fooMethod(Entity entityToPersist) {
            CDI.current().select(EntityRepository.class).get().persist(entityToPersist);

            return entityToPersist;

        }

    }
```

Is throwing

```
Transaction is not active, consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate one.
```

Any suggestion?
As alternative I have though to call the base "POST", but I have not found a way to do it.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have the right `@Transactional` annotation (`javax.transaction.Transactional` for quarkus `2.x`; `jakarta.transaction.Transactional` for quarkus `3.x`)?

Comment: yep, i'm adding the relevant import on the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the annotation `@Transactional` does not work for interfaces, so you need to use the programmatic approach:

```java
@ResourceProperties
public interface EntityResource extends PanacheRepositoryResource<EntityRepository, Entity, Long> {

        @POST
        @Path("/foo")
        @Transactional
        default Entity fooMethod(Entity entityToPersist) {

            QuarkusTransaction.requiringNew().run(() -> {
                  entityToPersist.persist();
            });

            return entityToPersist;
        }

}
```

You can find more information about the programmatic approach here: https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#programmatic-approach

By the way, the very same limitation was found when using REST Data with Panache and Reactive and was fixed by https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/34542 (will be part of Quarkus 3.3). I will see if we can implement the same fix in REST Data with Panache and ORM.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Reported in Quarkus for further discussion: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35107